# How to find List element with class without looping unity c#

Tags: c#, list, loops, find, unityscript

How to find element in List class without looping ?

for example ordinary look up using Looping :

```
for(int i = 0; i < inventoryx.Player.items.Count; i++) {
            if(inventoryx.Player.items[i].itemName == "Wood") {
                Debug.log("You Find The Wood");
            }
            else {
                Debug.Log("Can't Find The Wood");
            }
        }
```

items.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// Make Class Item

public class item {
    public string itemName;
    public int itemID;
    public string itemDesc;
    public string itemIcon;
    public GameObject itemModel;
    public int itemTime;
    public int hightprice;
    public int stdprice;
    public int itemStock;
    public int harvest;
    public RawTree rawTree;
    public ItemType itemType;
    public ItemProd itemProd;
    public ItemLocation itemLocation;
    public int Lvlunlock;
    private string baseName;
    public int itemExp;

    public enum ItemType {
        Raw,
        Admirable,
        Valuable
    }

    public enum RawTree {
        BigTree,
        SmallTree,
        Field,
        None
    }

    public enum ItemProd {
        Corps,
        Dairy,
        JuiceJamMaker,
        Kitchen,
        Bakery,
        CraftHouse,
        ChickenCoop,
        FishingSpotMountain,
        CowPasture,
        LunaMine,
        PigPen,
        FishingSpotLake,
        TropicalWood,
        SheepPasture,
        FishingSpotSea,
        Beebox,
        HomeIndustry
    }

    public enum ItemLocation { 
        Home,
        Orchard
    }

    public item (string name, int ID, string desc, int harvestx, int time, int stdpricex, int hightpricex, int stock, int Lvlunlockx, RawTree RawTree, ItemType type, ItemProd prod, string folderx, ItemLocation location, int Exp) {
        itemName = name;
        itemID = ID;
        itemDesc = desc;
        harvest = harvestx;
        itemTime = time;
        stdprice = stdpricex;
        hightprice = hightpricex;
        itemStock = stock;
        Lvlunlock = Lvlunlockx;
        rawTree = RawTree;
        itemType = type;
        itemProd = prod;
        itemIcon = folderx;
        itemLocation = location;
        itemExp = Exp;
    }

    public item() {

    }
}
```

Is there any idea to find an items without looping such as above ?
because using looping to find the elements data is take more memory to do it. If there is more than 100 items it will make it lag and take more time.

Thanks

Comment: when found the item then you can exit the loop. one way or the other you have to loop through the item. LINQ could hide the loop, but still uses a one.

Comment: What type is Player.items?

Comment: If the names are unique, then you can use, inventoryx.Player.items.ToDictionary(p=>p.itemName); Then you can access inventoryx.Player.items["Wood"]

Comment: Would converting to a dictionary not enumarate through items as well @AnoopJoshi?

Comment: using for loop like what you are doing or using linq. Add "break;" after "Debug.log("You Find The Wood");"

Comment: @Mfusiki, Player.items is a class. See code above i have modified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ you can write

```
using Sytem.Linq;
...

bool hasWood = inventoryx.Player.items.Any(i => i.ItemName == "Wood");
```

Or, to find the index:

```
int index = items.FindIndex(i => i.ItemName == "Wood");
```

Which returns the index of the first item matching the condition, or -1 to indicate no matches found.

This will still be O(n) though, just like your loop, but it is a bit more terse and readable.

Also, C# offers a `foreach` statement for iterating through `IEnumerable` collections, this helps prevent off-by-one exceptions:

```
foreach (var item in inventoryx.Player.items)
{
    if (item.ItemName == "Wood")
        Debug.log("You Find The Wood");
}
```

Comment: What about if find the items name it will return the index of the List items Using LINQ ?

Comment: You can use `int index = items.FindIndex(i => i.ItemName == "Wood");`, this will return either the first index, or -1 if the condition can't be matched.

Comment: Yes, This is absolutely what i want. Thanks James Jenkinson.

Answer (score 3):

To make this more efficient for many items you can consider creating a dictionary, mapping `itemName`s to items:

```
Dictionary<string, Item> itemNamesToItem = inventoryx.Player.items.ToDictionary(i => i.itemName, i => i);
```

Then you can access the items by name:

```
if (itemNamesToItem.ContainsKey("Wood"))
    Debug.log("You Find The Wood");
else
    Debug.Log("Can't Find The Wood");
```

Of course you can only do this if the `itemName`s are unique. And you probably should store this dictionary per player, maybe as property of the player, so you don't have to recreate it everytime you want to look up an item.

---

If the `itemName`s are not unique, you could consider making a dictionary mapping `itemName` to a list of items:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Item>> itemNamesToItem =
    inventoryx.Player.items.GroupBy(i => i.itemName)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: What about if in List element there is same itemName ?

Comment: Then this approach won't work, because the keys in the dictionary must be unique. For you're purpose (to find out if there is _at least one_ element with that name) this could work if you only add one item with that name. But you can't do this using `ToDictionary` but would have to build the dictionary manually.